# From random function in cpp to qml

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have a class and I can get data from the constructor to show it in the TableView in qml, but the problem is when I want to show data from anoher function from that class. For example:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQuickView>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include "myclass.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    MyModel *myTable=new MyModel;
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("myTable", myTable);
    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);

    return app.exec();

}
```

**MyModel.h**

```
struct Info
{
    QString name;
    QString address;
    QString values;
    QString salary;
};

class MyModel : public QAbstractTableModel
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MyModel(QObject *parent=nullptr);
.
////some variables declared////
.
Q_INVOKABLE int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override;
Q_INVOKABLE int columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override;
Q_INVOKABLE QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role=Qt::DisplayRole) const override;
Q_INVOKABLE QHash<int,QByteArray> roleNames() const override;
private:
    QList<Votes> m_model;
```

**MyModel.cpp**

```
MyModel::MyModel(QObject *parent)
    : QAbstractTableModel{parent}
{
    m_model.append({"name1","add1","value1","salary1"});
    m_model.append({"name2", "add2","value2","salary2"});
    m_model.append({"name3","add3","value3","salary3"});
} ////I can see this in TableView

void MyModel::mapTable(QVector<QStringList> mapGroup)
{
    for(int i=0;i<mapGroup.count();i++)
    {
        m_model.append ({mapGroup[i][0], mapGroup[i][1], mapGroup[i][2], mapGroup[i][3});
    }
} ////I cannot see this in TableView

...
```

**MyModel.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4 as CI

CI.TableView
{
    model: myTable

CI.TableViewColumn
{
    role: "name"
    title:"Name"
    width: 100
}
CI.TableViewColumn
{
    role: "add"
    title:"Address"
    width: 100
}
CI.TableViewColumn
{
    role: "value"
    title:"Value"
    width: 100
}
CI.TableViewColumn
{
    role: "salary"
    title:"Salary"
    width: 100
}
}
```

**Dialog.qml**

```
...
Rectangle
    {
        id: tableRec
        width: parent.width/1.5
        height: parent.height/2

        MyModel
        {
            id: infoTable
            width: tableRec.width
            height: tableRec.height
            anchors.fill: parent

            rowDelegate: Rectangle
            {
                id: rowTable
                height: 15

                SystemPalette
                {
                    id: myPalette
                    colorGroup: SystemPalette.Active
                }
                color:
                {
                    var baseColor = styleData.alternate?myPalette.alternateBase:myPalette.base
                    return styleData.selected?myPalette.highlight:baseColor
                }
            }

            itemDelegate: Item
            {
                Text
                {
//                    anchors.centerIn: parent
                    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                    text: styleData.value
                    font.pixelSize: Math.round(infoTable.height)/16
                }
            }
        }
```

How can I pass the data from mapTable function to TableView? I get that it has something to do with QAbstractTableModel, but I cannot make it work.

Comment: You have to notify the view that you inserted new rows with `beginInsertRow` and `endInsertRow`

Comment: Its updated now

Answer (score 0):

When you create a custom model based on an inner data model, you have to notify the views that you inserted/removed rows.

The model cannot know when you change its inner model. That's why you have to use `beginInsertRows` and `endInsertRow` in your `mapTable` method.

A quick example:

```
class MyModel: public QAbstractListModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyModel(QObject* parent=nullptr): QAbstractListModel (parent)
    {
        innerModel.append("Bob");
        innerModel.append("Patrick");
        innerModel.append("Alice");
    }
    Q_INVOKABLE int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override
    {
        if (parent.isValid())
            return 0;
        return innerModel.size();
    }
    Q_INVOKABLE int columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override
    {
        if (parent.isValid())
            return 0;
        return 2;
    }
    Q_INVOKABLE QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role=Qt::DisplayRole) const override
    {
        qDebug() << index << role;
        switch (role)
        {
            case Qt::DisplayRole:
            case Qt::UserRole + 1:
                return innerModel.at(index.row());
            case Qt::UserRole + 2:
                return QString::number(index.row() + 1);
        }
        return QVariant();
    }

    Q_INVOKABLE QHash<int,QByteArray> roleNames() const override
    {
        QHash<int,QByteArray> roles;
        roles.insert(Qt::UserRole + 1, "name");
        roles.insert(Qt::UserRole + 2, "index");
        return roles;
    }

    Q_INVOKABLE void add(QString const& name)
    {
        beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), rowCount(), rowCount());
        innerModel.append(name);
        endInsertRows();
    }
    private:
        QList<QString> innerModel;
};
```

```
Item {
    anchors.fill: parent
        TextEdit {
            width: 100
            id: name
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.top: parent.top
        }
        Button {
            text: "save"
            onClicked: theModel.add(name.text)
            anchors.left: name.right
            anchors.top: parent.top
        }
    ListView {
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        anchors.top: name.bottom
        model: theModel
        delegate: Text {
            text: name
        }
    }
}
```

If you comment `beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), rowCount(), rowCount());` and `endInsertRows` in the method `add`, you will not be able to see the new rows int the list because the model cannot know when its inner model has changed.

Comment: the `virtual` keyword is redundant here.

Comment: Removed, thanks. But, feel free to edit my answer if you see mistakes

Comment: @RomhaKorev Thank you for your answer... If I'm not wrong, you append items to innerModel in the constructor. That works for me also, like I wrote in the question, but if there is another function and I pass some data to that function and then show that data in the table view it doesnt work.

Comment: In my model, I added a method `add` which is called from the QML part when you click on the button. It will add the value in the text field to the model and the view is updated thanks to `beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), rowCount(), rowCount());` and `endInsertRows()`